# issue in html mail template which have other language

Tags: html, encode

i am trying to pass the html code to OneSignal service as a body. But my mail has some Portuguese language content which is converted in other symbols in mail. 
How can i convert it to readable Portuguese content ?

Below is the code, how i pass the body in OneSignalService:

```
var body = $scope.mailBody;    
body = body.replace("{HE_ID}", id).replace("{HE_Name}", name);    
body = $('<div></div>').append(body).html();    
OneSignalService.SendMail($scope.HE_StatusTitle, body, "abc@abc.com", "xyz@mailinator.com")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to a mismatch in the character encoding between the web form (which is determined by the "Content-type:" header sent by your server) and what is being sent in the e-mail. The latter is likely determined by the `OneSignalService.SendMail()` function, I do not know about it. It may be sending a Content-type mail header with an encoding different from the one you have on the page or it might not be sending any encoding at all (in that case, the recipient e-mail client decides what encoding to use).

The content of your question doesn't provide enough info to make correct guesses as to what exactly happened, but I would recommend the following:

- ensure that your server sends "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" in the HTML headers.
- check the configuration of your mail sender (OneSignal) and ensure that it is set to send e-mail in the "utf-8" encoding (and emits the appropriate SMTP mail header).
- you could also add `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the `<head>` section both on your HTML page that has the mail entry form and in the HTML that you send as e-mail. This alone is not guaranteed to solve the issue, though (browsers will honor the HTTP header with priority and might ignore the "meta" tag).

Comment: i have tried it by adding and removing the meta tag, but it remain same.